# Js edited div content disappears

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi I'm appending content to the div, after an `ajax` call success. But quickly the appended text disappears. Why that happens, could you please help?

My `js` is kept in another file and `js` is called via a button click event.

**HTML:**

```
<html>

  <head> </head>

  <body>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jq/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/script.js'></script>
    <br/>

    <form name="form">
        <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname">
        <input type="submit" onclick="postData()" id="data-submit"> 
    </form>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <div id="feedback"></div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      //this sometimes show errors on google chrome. 
      //$(document).ready(function(){});
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is the full content of my `js` file

```
function postData(){                
    var uname=$('#uname').val();    
    $.ajax({
            url:'checkempcode.php',
            data: {name: uname},
            type: "POST",           
            async: false,
            success: function(data){
                window.alert('Checking');
                $('#feedback').html(data);
                $( "#feedback" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
            }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Can you share your html too

Comment: @gilsha thanks for your edit

Comment: @Bineesh my guess is that the data which you are getting from ajax call is not properly formatted and that might be leading to this issue, did you happened to check the data that is coming from ajax call? is it well formatted?

Comment: actually evenif i insert some text also , it disappears. but yes, the data returned is jason type arraye using json_encode(array($......));

Comment: is there any reason the html or calling main page is reloaded after ajax success also ?

Comment: This link may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617060/content-disappears-immediately-after-form-submitted-and-function-runs

Comment: The page get reloaded since the submit buttons are submitting your form. Try changing the button type from `submit` to `button`

Comment: it is solved by removing form tags in html and using the button type instead of submit

Comment: @ozil, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The page get reloaded since the submit buttons are submitting your form. Try changing the button type from `submit` to `button`

```
 <input type="button" onclick="postData()" id="data-submit"/>
```

OR

Add return false in `onclick` function;

```
 <input type="submit" onclick="postData(); return false;" id="data-submit"/>
```

Comment: thank you ; it worked. saved my another 2 hours. ( last 2 hours i lost on this issue )

Answer (score 0):

You should just add `event.preventDefault()` to you function to prevent form from submiting :

```
function postData(){              
    event.preventDefault();

    var uname=$('#uname').val();    
    $.ajax({
            url:'checkempcode.php',
            data: {name: uname},
            type: "POST",           
            async: false,
            success: function(data){
                window.alert('Checking');
                $('#feedback').html(data);
                $( "#feedback" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
            }
    }); 
}
```

Hope this helps.